# Angular / Breeze - camelCasing in model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, hottowel

I am just starting to learn Angular, and have been working with John Papa's course on Pluralsight to try and get my head around it. I was having a problem binding some data to a page, and it turned out to be an incorrect casing.

I had:

```
 <small>{{s.timeslot.name}}</small> at <small>{{s.room.name}}</small>
```

when I should have had:

```
 <small>{{s.timeSlot.name}}</small> at <small>{{s.room.name}}</small>
```

That's fine, but I just can't understand why.

The data is returned from Web API with this method (note no camelcase on timeslots):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Lookups()
    {
        var rooms = _repository.Rooms;
        var tracks = _repository.Tracks;
        var timeslots = _repository.TimeSlots;
        return new { rooms, tracks, timeslots };
    }
```

An angular service called datacontext.js has the following object to map between (at least to my understanding) Web API names and Breeze entity names.

```
    var entityNames = {
        attendee: 'Person',
        person: 'Person',
        speaker: 'Person',
        session: 'Session',
        room: 'Room',
        track: 'Track',
        timeslot: 'TimeSlot'
    }
```

There are some further functions that involve caching data, and extending the model on the client, but nowhere is there a reference to timeSlot (with camelCase).

What is happening here, is a convention for HTML casing being enforced by Angular?

EDIT: Thanks to Ward for the answer. For anyone following the same course who has a similar question, breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault() is called in entityManagerFactory.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bit of "sloppiness" in the spelling of "TimeSlot" in various places.

Your binding to "s" is a binding to the `Session` type.  The `Session` type itself dictates the spelling of any of its navigation properties. Everything else is irrelevant.

The metadata for `Session` is generated on the server based on the C# "Session" class. There you will find that the navigation property is spelled "TimeSlot".

Your client is using the Breeze `NamingConvention.camelCase` to translate between the preferred PascalCasing of C# and the preferend camelCasing in JavaScript apps. Therefore, on the Breeze client you should expect "TimeSlot" navigation property to become "timeSlot".

> Entity names are not translated by the `NamingConvention` (at this time). The C# type, "TimeSlot" is also spelled "TimeSlot" for the JavaScript type.

Every other spelling everywhere else is irrelevant for this binding.

You may find the "[Query result debugging](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-result-debugging)" documentation topic helpful.